# MySQL stored procedure set dynamic query from in parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I try to make one query inside stored procedure to another database (same server).
Everything OK, but I need to use dynamic database name received from in parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_sp(
 IN in_db_name VARCHAR(32),
 OUT out_result VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN   
  /*This working OK*/
  SELECT my_col INTO out_result FROM another_db.my_table WHERE id = 1;

  /*This NOT WORK :( */
  SELECT my_col INTO out_result FROM @in_db_name.my_table WHERE id = 1;
END;
```

Comment: You cannot change table names in statement preparation, only parameter values. Prepared statement is the preparation in which database prepares (explain) plan for executing this query in advance and uses this the same prepared plan for query execution with different parameters. If one changes the table name, then this is completely different execution plan for database and database system has to recalculate execution plan from scratch. That's not the point of preparation in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic query for that purpose.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_sp(
 IN in_db_name VARCHAR(32),
 OUT out_result VARCHAR(32)
)
SET @s =  (concat ("SELECT my_col INTO out_result FROM " ,  in_db_name.my_table , " WHERE id = 1;"
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: Your answer seem be logically correct, but not work. I have declared @s as varchar(255) ... i have added two closing parenthesis which are missing )).  -> (concat ("SELECT my_col INTO out_result FROM " ,  in_db_name.my_table , " WHERE id = 1;"))  . Also I tried: ... , in_db_name, ".my_table ..." . But not work

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `my_sp` (
    IN `in_db_name` VARCHAR(32),
    OUT `out_result` VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN   
    SET @`query` := CONCAT('SELECT `my_col` INTO @`_out_result` 
                            FROM `', `in_db_name`, '`.`my_table` 
                            WHERE `id` = 1');
    PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`query`;
    EXECUTE `stmt`;
    SET `out_result` := @`_out_result`;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

See [14.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Example:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (
    ->     `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->     `my_col` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `my_table` (`my_col`)
    -> VALUES ('ONE');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `my_sp` (
    ->     IN `in_db_name` VARCHAR(32),
    ->     OUT `out_result` VARCHAR(32)
    -> )
    -> BEGIN   
    ->     SET @`query` := CONCAT('SELECT `my_col` INTO @`_out_result` 
    '>                             FROM `', `in_db_name`, '`.`my_table` 
    '>                             WHERE `id` = 1');
    ->     PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`query`;
    ->     EXECUTE `stmt`;
    ->     SET `out_result` := @`_out_result`;
    ->     DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `my_sp`('test', @`my_out_result`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`my_out_result`;
+------------------+
| @`my_out_result` |
+------------------+
| ONE              |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Not work. For testing I decide to use concat from the original query (without parameters). 
concat("SELECT my_col INTO out_result FROM ", "another_db.my_table" ," WHERE id = 1;") ... <- So there i have concatenate mi first working query ... and NOT WORK .... so something wrong with prepared stmt

Comment: @MTK: See example in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for you time. Still not work. I see your example and I belive that in your computer work. I dont know why but for example in mi case if I not declare @query variable I got error ( In your case NOT) . I tried step by step and Evrithing Ok until I write this line "PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`query`;" .... Need stmt to be declared (what type ? ). I can't find that in mysql manual ( they say also like you set variable = value ... but in mi case if I not declared previous this variable got error ... I am very confused with that )

Comment: @MTK: Note the difference between [10.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) and [14.6.4 Variables in Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-variables.html).

Comment: I  have see and thank's, it but nothing to clarify there. I have maked another question more clearly about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594858/mysql-stored-procedure-execute-prepare-statement-not-working