# mysql stored procedure execute prepare statement not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to use prepared statement inside stored procedure but I do not understand why it does not work. I have mysql5.7.9 and I call it from PHP->PDO

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_sp(
  OUT out_result VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN

  /*This work OK*/
  SELECT pow(2,2) INTO out_result;

  /*NOT work Variable prefixed with @   */
  SELECT pow(2,2) INTO @out_result;

  /*NOT work (with or without @ before out_result variable)*/
  PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT pow(2,2) INTO out_result';
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not delcaring @out_result as a variable

Try adding this just below BEGIN

```
SET @out_result = out_result;
```